# How to change the color of a sphere after crossing a cube in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, random, colors

I am new Unity3D, I really love it, and when I started my project, I have a problem, I have a sphere which it moves by (AddForce), and I put a Material to it which is (red), I want from that sphere after crossing a cube which it is on (isTrigger) mode and not visible is:

1. Change the color of the sphere to (blue or red).
2. To Start the sphere into a random color (blue or red).
3. If I can put a Hex color, It would be better, but if it a solid color, no problem.
4. If the random color = to cube 1 color it will continue moving, else: random color != to cube 1 it will stop moving, you could say that it is an obstacle.

I really believe that it wants coding, but I only know Python, so if you can write for me the code to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

The color of your sphere is defined by the matelial you applied on it.

```
var sphere = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
sphere.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code example for random color

```
void Start()
{
    int a=Random.Range(0,2);
    var sphere =GetComponent<Renderer>();
    sphere.material.SetColor("_Color",a==0?Color.Blue:Color.Red);
}
```

This should solve the random color problem

Comment: Hi @Bartek Dusza, Thank you for the code I really appreciate that it worked for me, but is there any way to put a Hex number or put a light Blue?

Comment: And if you know to answer this question I would be grateful, can I let the code that if the color = to blue it will continue moving in the blue floor, else: stop, and the something with the red: color = to red it will continue moving in the red floor, else: stop................ Thank you very much.

Comment: Well i never used hexCodes, but you can check the color with sphere.material.color==Color.Blue or Color.Red

Comment: Well, I checked the color, but the problem is that the blue is dark, but anyway thanks, and do you have any thoughts about the question that I mentioned above?

Comment: Well the dark color could be from that the cube starts with already set color, i think the best thing to do is set the color on the material to white because sometimes they can break. Check it and let me knows.

Comment: Hi, Actually It is the same thing, nothing happened, anyways thank you.

Comment: But I really have a problem, and my consest of two Obstacles,  One is blue (Obstacle 1) and the other is Red(Obstacle 2), and my problem is: I want if the sphere color = red, it can run in (Obstacle 1), and cant run in  (Obstacle 2), but if the sphere color = blue, it can run in (Obstacle 2), and cant run in  (Obstacle 1), hope that you understand

Comment: my project consist *

Comment: I think you can do it with OnCollisionStay methods do you would check the color with collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>() and check it, I'm gonna write some pseudoCode if(color==Color.red) CanWalk=true; you get the point

Comment: Does this work: if(color==Color.red) CanWalk=true; ?

Comment: And I have collision so I think I must write this for every cube